# OS X compile error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile

New to compiling here, so bear with me.  I'm trying to compile some c++ code on OS X 10.10.3 using `make`. I have XCode 6.3.1 installed. My Makefile was generated using qmake.  The compiler runs well until it tries to run the final build command and throws an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      puntoexe::charsetConversionIconv::myIconv(void*, char*, unsigned long) const in charsetConversionIconv.o
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      puntoexe::charsetConversionIconv::close() in charsetConversionIconv.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      puntoexe::charsetConversionIconv::initialize(int) in charsetConversionIconv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [dicom2jpeg.app/Contents/MacOS/dicom2jpeg] Error 1
```

I have found multiple threads here describing a similar problem, and apparently it comes down to the compiler linking to a 32 bit library.  The main suggestion that works for others is to add the following code to the Makefile:

```
-stdlib=libstdc++
```

The qmake-generated Makefile looks like this:

```
CC            = clang
CXX           = clang++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG
CFLAGS        = -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/mkspecs/unsupported/macx-clang-libc++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/include -I.
LINK          = clang++
LFLAGS        = -headerpad_max_install_names -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib -lpthread
```

So, I've changed my Makefile to link to the appropriate library:

```
CC            = clang
CXX           = clang++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG
CFLAGS        = -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/mkspecs/unsupported/macx-clang-libc++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/include -I.
LINK          = clang++
LFLAGS        = -headerpad_max_install_names -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib -lpthread
```

But, no dice.  Still throwing the same error on final build.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the linker error messages, specifically which symbols are not being found ?

Comment: Of course, just added them.

Comment: Do you have `#include <iconv.h>` in charsetConversionIconv.cpp ?

Comment: No, I don't see it.  When I add `#include <iconv.h>` or `#include "/usr/include/iconv.h"` I still throw the error.

Comment: Linker must link to `libiconv.dylib` library. You have to add `-liconv` flag to `LDFLAGS` or add the library in Xcode project. I don't think `-stdlib=libstdc++` is needed.

Comment: -liconv addition to LDFLAGS worked.  Thanks baf.  If you add the answer I'll +1 you.